# Does AJAX have any special security concerns?

Tags: ajax, security, post, browser, request

I know all about SQL injections, and peeking into javascript files that a website uses, and also that GET requests contain all of the information in a URL.

Is there any security concern that is special to AJAX and only pertains to using AJAX?

For example, sending post requests via AJAX seems completely safe to me. Barring SQL injections, I can't think of one thing that could go wrong... is this the correct case?

Also, are "requests" of any kind that a user's browser sends or any information it receives available to be viewed by a third party who should not be viewing? And can that happen to AJAX post requests ('post' requests specifically; not 'get')?

Comment: Start with reading https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project

Answer (score 2):

It's like any other form of data input: validate your values, check the referrer, authenticate the session, use SSL.

Comment: I'm guessing this would be to minimise XSRF attacks... But a token based approach would be better IMHO.